# hive order by is not working in a subquery

Tags: hive

I have this query -

```
CREATE TABLE traces_orc1 
(pc BIGINT, 
 opcode STRING, 
 frequency STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '44' 
STORED AS ORC;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE traces_orc1 
SELECT CONV(pc,16,10) as pc, 
opcode, COUNT(*) 
FROM traces_texttemp as frequency 
GROUP BY pc, opcode;


CREATE TABLE traces_orctemp 
(pc BIGINT, 
 opcode STRING, 
 frequency STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '44' 
STORED AS ORC;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE traces_orctemp 
SELECT pc, opcode, frequency FROM traces_orc1 ORDER BY pc ASC;
```

I am trying to merge these two statements in one like -

```
CREATE TABLE traces_orc2 (
pcount BIGINT, 
opcode STRING, 
frequency STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '44' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE traces_orc2 
SELECT CONV(TRIM(traces_text.pc),16,10) as pcount, 
opcode, COUNT(*) as frequency 
FROM traces_text
GROUP BY pcount,opcode
ORDER BY pcount ASC;
```

but this wont work. The `order by` is not working when i write it as one statement

Any inputs ??

Comment: you have `traces_texttemp` in your 1st overwrite and `traces_text` in your 3rd overwrite.  Where did these come from?

Comment: These are just the two tables from where i am loading the data

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE traces_orc2 
select pcount, opcode, frequency from 
(SELECT CONV(TRIM(traces_text.pc),16,10) as pcount, 
opcode, COUNT(*) as frequency 
FROM traces_text
GROUP BY pcount,opcode)
ORDER BY pcount ASC;
```

It may force Hive to fire a second reduce phase for the sorting.